# TFS - Add group to all projects

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to add a TFS group to all projects in TFS.

Instead of clicking into each one seperatly and adding the TFS group to each project team.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No way to add a TFS group to all Teams at the same time in a team project by default.

You can try to use [IIdentityManagementService.AddMemberToApplicationGroup Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.iidentitymanagementservice.addmembertoapplicationgroup(v=vs.120).aspx) to Add members to Team or Group.

You can read more here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2011/12/07/tfs-api-part-41manage-groups-and-members/, note that `IGroupSecurityService` is obsolete. You need to use the `IIdentityManagementService` or `ISecurityService` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you add the group/person to the TFS Collection instead of the TFS Projects.